# ReactJS manage lots of select state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given I have this code (I removed a lot of the select items so it wasn't a massive list but there would be an extra 20 or so):

```
import * as React from "react";

import { Form, Card, Grid } from "tabler-react";
import { Button } from "semantic-ui-react";

class Skills extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     showSaveButton: false,
     showCancelButton: false,
    };
  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        showSaveButton: true,
        showCancelButton: true,
      });
  }

  cancelChanges = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        showSaveButton: false,
        showCancelButton: false,
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card" name="skills">
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>Top skills</Card.Title>
          <Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Col offset={1} md={10}>
              <Form.Group name="softskills" label="Soft Skills">
                <Form.SelectGroup canSelectMultiple pills onChange={this.onChange}>
                  <Form.SelectGroupItem
                    label="Communication"
                    name="communication"
                    value="Communication"
                  />
                  <Form.SelectGroupItem
                    label="Teamwork"
                    name="teamwork"
                    value="Teamwork"
                  />
             </Form.SelectGroup>
              </Form.Group>
            </Grid.Col>
          </Grid.Row>
          <Button content='Cancel changes' floated='left' color='red' basic hidden={this.state.showCancelButton ? '' : 'hidden'} onClick={this.cancelChanges}/>
          <Button content='Save changes' floated='right' color='green' basic hidden={this.state.showSaveButton ? '' : 'hidden'}/>
        </Card.Body>
 </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Skills;
```

The current functionality is that on change, 2 buttons will appear that are cancel or accept.
I need the below functionality but I can't work out how to do it unless I have like 60+ states (an initial and a working state for each option) which seems ridiculous:

- The initial state is pulled from a database in a JSON array whereby everything that appears in that array should start out as selected (checked=true). For example, if the array is ["communication", "timemanagement"] I need to set the Communication and Time Management options to checked=true.
- The initial state needs to be saved so that if anything changes and then the user clicks cancel, the checked boolean for each option is reset to what it was originally
- If accept is clicked, the information needs to be sent to the database and so it needs to know what options have checked=true and be able to grab their names

So is there a way to do this without having a massive amount of states?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a mapping in state for all 60. When you get the results from the database, store them in state with fields to track checked and changed statuses:

```
// isDirty is a flag to say there are pending changes on the option
const options = arrayFromDatabase.map(arrayElement => ({ name: arrayElement, checked: true, isDirty: false })
```

then store that array in your state, e.g.,

```
this.setState({...this.state, options })
```

When a change is made, mark the specific option as dirty -> `isDirty = true`. If it's cancelled, flip the flag back to false -> `isDirty = false`.

```
Should look something like, 

this.setState({ 
    ...state, 
    options: this.state.map(
        option => option.name === valueToChange ? { 
            ...option, 
            isDirty: true | false } : 
        option
    )
})
```

Handle your check-changed in the same way.